# How override view on custom tab?

Tags: reporting, tab, pageblocksection, custom-view, view

[image: standard tab]

I want to make report section for view in custom tab. I d'nt understand how override view.  There is visual page for this but  i can't use View filter for my tab. For example, there are 2 views: sales, marketing. For each view i want to show appropriate Report list.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are mixing a few things up here. The View mechanism is limited to filtering **lists of records**. The capabilities are those you see when you press "Edit" or "Create New View" beside the picklist - that's it.

**It is not possible, to integrate Reports in the List(views) picklist.**

The option to override the View by a visualforce page is something entirely different and I would possibly call it a naming-clash. This "View" there means the view of a **single record**. You can open each record in salesforce either in "View" or "Edit-Mode" - both can be overridden by VF-Pages.

To get things clear in your mind think about the views in your screenshot as list-views and the overridable ones as record-views.

Another thing what you can do is to override the entire tab. And with that you might come a bit closer to what you want, since you could write there you own titlepage for your tab. As a tradeoff, you loose all the default mechanisms for listviews and you have to (re)create the picklist and all the logic you need on your own.